# Stoichiometry consumed/generated

Tags: stoichiometry

NaHCO3(aq) + H3C6H5O7(aq) = H2O(l) + CO2(g) + NaC6H5O7(aq)
9 NaHCO3(aq) + 8 H3C6H5O7(aq) = 14 H2O(l) + 3 CO2(g) + 9 NaC6H5O7(aq)

List at least 2 types of reactions that the equation in question #2 can be categorized as?
If 0.950 grams of citric acid  (C6H8O7) reacts
How many moles of sodium bicarbonate will be consumed
How many moles of carbon dioxide will be generated
How many grams of carbon dioxide will be generated

One type of reaction is combustion  What would be the second?

Convert grams to moles
.950 g  citric acid x (1 mole/ 192.123 grams C6H8O7) = .005 moles of  C6H8O7

how many moles of sodium bicarbonate will be consumed
 .005 moles of  C6H8O7 x (9 moles NaHCO3/1 mole of C6H8O7) = .045 moles of NaHCO3

how many moles of carbon dioxide will be generated
 .005 moles of  C6H8O7 x (14 moles H2O/1 mole of C6H8O7) = .07 moles of H2O

how many grams of carbon dioxide will be generated
.07 moles of H2O x (18.015 grams of H2O/1mole H2O) = 1.261 grams of H2O

Comment: It's refreshing to see a homework question in which someone has included the work they've done so far, but do you have a question?  There are a number in the problem you've shown, but not one that you appear to be asking us.  In any case, I would start by rechecking the balanced chemical equation you've got.  You should need a 3:1 ratio of sodium bicarbonate and citric acid.

Comment: This is a question I have to study for a test   I do not know the type of reaction I have to list two.  I think the first one is combustion but I do not know the second type of reaction.  Also I want to know if my answer is correct of .45 moles of sodium bicarbonate consumed, .o7 moles of H2o produced and 1.261 grams of H20 produced.  If the answers are correct can I leave it or do I have to convert it to scientific notation.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I thought about what you said 3:1 ratio and I changed it to this would this be corrected? 
If 0.950 grams of citric acid  (C6H8O7) reacts
.950 g  citric acid x (1 mole/ 192.123 grams C6H8O7) = .00495 moles of  C6H8O7
how many moles of sodium bicarbonate will be consumed
 .00495 moles of  C6H8O7 x (3 moles NaHCO3/1 mole of C6H8O7) = .01485 moles of NaHCO3
how many moles of carbon dioxide will be generated
 .00495 moles of  C6H8O7 x (3 moles CO2/1 mole of C6H8O7) = .01485 moles of CO2

how many grams of carbon dioxide will be generated   .653 grams of CO2

Comment: would above be correct and what two types of reaction?  I think one is combustion

Comment: The correct balanced equation would be $\ce{3 NaHCO3 + H3C6H5O7 -> Na3C6H5O7 + 3 H2O + 3 CO2}$.  Your stoichiometry is correct with a corrected balanced equation.  The only reaction type I see here is an acid-base reaction.  I guess your instructor might be looking for a decomposition reaction as well; I'm not sure.